# SpringMVC validation with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, validation

In the project, I use SpringMVC and Ajax.

Therefore, for validating the input from the form submitted, I don't use SpringMVC's error tag to display error messages. Instead, I warp all errors into a object and return back to JSP for displaying them using jQuery.

As I know, Spring gets the error messages from the `messages.properties(e.g)` based on the key you set on the bean if using SpringMVC's errors tag.

**Question**

I want to exact the error message from the `messages.properites(e.g)` without using its' errors tag.

For now, I hard code the default error message in the validators in the project implementing `Validator` interface, but that's not what I want.

I want to exact the message s from `xxx.properties` based on the error I set.

What can I do?

Comment: Your question is too hard to understand, you need to provide us with code examples, expected input / output etc

Answer (score 0):

You need ResourceBundleMessageSource bean.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

In your controller

```
  @Autowired
  ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;


 @RequestMapping( "/your/url" )
 public @ResponseBody String doSomething( @RequestParam Long myVal ) {
    String errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage("error.code", Locale.getDefault());
    ...
    return ...;
 }
```